# JPA one to one bidirectional mapping is not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the below Employees and Departments classes, when I do a uni directional one to one mapping from employees to departments class its working fine , I am getting the employee details along with the department detail

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEES")
public class Employees implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
private Integer employee_id;

@Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
private String first_name;

@Column(name="LAST_NAME")
private String last_name;

@Column(name="EMAIL")
private String email;

@Column(name="PHONE_NUMBER")
private String phone_number;

@Column(name="HIRE_DATE")
private Date hire_date;

@Column(name="JOB_ID")
private String job_id;

@Column(name="SALARY")
private double salary;


@Column(name="COMMISSION_PCT")
private String commission_pct;

@Column(name="MANAGER_ID")
private String manager_id;


@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="department_id")
private Departments departments;

}
```

for the above mapping I am getting the result properly, but when I put the bi directional mapping in Departments class as below, getting error  while accessing the employees

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DEPARTMENTS")
public class Departments {
@Id
@Column(name="DEPARTMENT_ID")
private Integer department_id;

@Column(name="DEPARTMENT_NAME")
 private String department_name;

@Column(name="MANAGER_ID")
 private String manager_id;

@Column(name="LOCATION_ID")
 private String location_id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="departments")
private Employees employees;

public Employees getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}

}

    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener doOnLoad
INFO: HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 90, for class: com.example.demo.entity.Employees
```

Below is the code accessing the employees

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getEmployees",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Employees>> getEmployees(){
    System.out.println("Employees are ");
    List<Employees> employees =(List<Employees>) employeeRepo.findOne(new Integer(100));
    //System.out.println(employees.getDepartments());
    return new ResponseEntity(employees,HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

similarly below is the code for retreiving the departments which is giving the same result (recursive results ) multiple times with the bidirectional mapping

code for accessing the departments

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getDepartments",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Departments> getDepartments(){
        System.out.println("Departments are ");
        Departments dept = (Departments) departmentRepo.findOne(new Integer(10));

        return new ResponseEntity(dept,HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

Please someone help me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the right mapping.  While it may be true that each employee has just 1 department, each department presumably has more than 1 employee.  Thus the error you see on the query.  It's expecting just 1 employee, but got multiple.

Comment: do you mean one to one mapping should not be used in this case ?

Comment: Yes, typically you should use a `OneToMany` on the department and a `ManyToOne` on the employee.  Depending on your organizational hierarchy, you might even have a `ManyToMany` mapping on both.  Lastly, If you never want to go from the department side to the employee side, I've seen a mapping like that with a `OneToOne` unidirectional, which is not strictly correct, but sometimes generates the sql that you want.